# UITableView custom cell not displaying data

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios7, uiviewcontroller

Here is the story. I have a simple app in which I use 2 tabs, both of them with UITableView. The first tab/view is called `"Favorites"` and the second one is called `"My Profile."` In addition I have a custom UITable cell named `"CustomViewCell.xib"` with an identifier of the same name. `FavoritesViewController` is a subclass of UITableViewController and that one is running perfectly. But for the `ProfileViewController` I am using normal ViewController because I don't want the whole view to be UitableView. To make that possible, I the following to `ProfileViewController.h`:

```
@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

then in the `viewDidLoad` of ProfleViewController.m file I have:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomViewCell" bundle:nil]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomViewCell"];
```

The following methods are implemented just as in the other tab that's working:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.myArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      // Here I am customizing the cell and returning it. 
}
```

When i run the app, the cells are the right height, but are empty. 
To debug I put a break point right before cellForRowAtIndexPath, and the app runs without an error which it shouldn't. So, the program is not even getting to this method. So, I think that's the reason the cells are empty. Do you guys have any idea what might be causing it to skip this particular method? can you also explain it in simpler terms because I'm newbie, you know?

Comment: Did you assign the vc to be the delegate/datasource for the tableview? In viewdidload: self.tableview.delegate=self; self.tableview.datasource=self

Comment: You skipped the most important part of the code, and left irrelevant parts

Comment: You are right. Thank you sir! Such a silly silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `ViewDidLoad` method, add this code:

```
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
```

Then check again if the breakpoint works

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented a UITableViewDataSource? A UITableViewController is the delegate and datasource for the Table View it manages so you can define all those methods in the View Controller itself.

For a UITableView that is a subview of a UIViewController, you need to define the Table View's delegate and datasource.

See here: http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitableview-to-a-custom-uiview

Comment: And make sure you actually set the `dataSource` and/or `delegate` of your table view! The number of times I’ve forgotten to do that… *grumble grumble*

Comment: haha I just did that! Lesson learned mate! Silly mistake. In my defense though, I am new to IOS. Just started a week ago.